# QRunnable - how to implement WaitForFinished without a race?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have some I/O code in Qt that was moved to a `QRunnable` in order to avoid blocking the UI thread. This calls back with some queued slots to indicate its progress.

However I recently saw some issues where when the owner of the `QRunnable` is destroyed it can't delete the runnable until its complete (otherwise crash as the worker thread is still using it). To solve this I'd like to add a "`WaitForFinished`" to the runnable that it will call its in dtor so I can simply delete the `QRunnable` and know that it will block until its done before its dtor exits.

I thought this should be easy as all I need to do is use a `QMutex` in `QRunnable::run` implementation, then also acquire that mutex within `WaitForFinished`. However this has a race condition that I'm not sure how to solve.

Consider the following:

1. `QRunnable` is queued to be executed.
2. `QRunnable` starts to execute but `QRunnable::run` has not yet been called
3. The main thread deletes the `QRunnable` which calls `WaitForFinished` in the dtor and acquires the `QMutex` before `QRunnable::run` - so we assume its not running or finished running and destruct the `QRunnable`, but it hasn't even started yet!

Comment: QRunnable can be deleted by the Qt system if you set autodelete. Why don't you want to use this feature?

Comment: Either way I would still want the runnable to be stopped after the object which created it is destroyed.

Comment: Does _the  oreder of the operations matter_: deletion of owner object and deletion of runnable objects it started? I mean, what if runnable will be terminated shortly after the owner object, is it allowed?

Comment: No because the runnable shares data with the owner

Comment: Waiting in a derivable runnable's destructor is a no-no: when the base class's destructor runs, the derived class's destructor has already wiped it, all the while the thread is still using it. So, you can either explicitly call `wait()` in each and every derived class's destructor, or - as I've proposed - you use a final wrapper class that you manages some other runnable's life, and is used as a stand-in.

Answer (score 1):

You should acquire the mutex when runnable is constructed, and release it when `run()` is winding down. This must include when `run()` doesn't return at all - a thrown exception is *not* a return! You cannot arbitrarily delete a runnable in two circumstances:

1. once it is submitted to the thread pool, prior to it having finished,
2. if autoDelete is set.

   *After* `QRunnable::run()` has returned within the threadpool's implementation, an internal reference counter in the runnable will be decremented iff a cached value of `autoDelete` was true. This would cause a dangling pointer dereference.

Below is a tested implementation of this idea.

The output is:

```
~Incrementer 
1 
~Incrementer 
2
```

```cpp
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QDebug>

// This cannot be a class that can be derived from, since the destructor
// will be run *after* the derived class's destructor - thus it would not
// protect the derived class's members from premature destruction.
class RunnableWrapper Q_DECL_FINAL : public QRunnable {
   Q_DISABLE_COPY(RunnableWrapper)
   class LockerUnlocker {
      Q_DISABLE_COPY(LockerUnlocker)
      QMutexLocker * m_mutexLocker;
   public:
      explicit LockerUnlocker(QMutexLocker * m) : m_mutexLocker(m) {}
      ~LockerUnlocker() { m_mutexLocker->unlock(); }
   };
   QRunnable * m_wrapped;
   QMutex m_mutex;
   QMutexLocker m_lock;
   void run() Q_DECL_FINAL {
      LockerUnlocker unlocker(&m_lock);
      m_wrapped->run();
   }
public:
   RunnableWrapper(QRunnable * r) : m_wrapped(r), m_lock(&m_mutex) {
      setAutoDelete(false);
   }
   void wait() { QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex); }
   ~RunnableWrapper() {
      wait();
      if (m_wrapped->autoDelete()) delete m_wrapped;
   }
};

class Incrementer : public QRunnable {
   int * m_val;
   void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { ++ *m_val; }
public:
   explicit Incrementer(int * val) : m_val(val) {}
   ~Incrementer() { qDebug() << __FUNCTION__; }
};

int main() {
   QThreadPool pool;
   int i = 0;
   {
      // Use with stack allocated runnable
      Incrementer inc(&i);
      inc.setAutoDelete(false); // Required without a wrapper as well!
      RunnableWrapper wrap(&inc);
      pool.start(&wrap);
   }
   qDebug() << i;
   {
      // Use with heap allocated runnable
      Incrementer * inc = new Incrementer(&i);
      RunnableWrapper wrap(inc);
      pool.start(&wrap);
   }
   qDebug() << i;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no *one size fits all* solution. Preferred method will depend on the task details. While I've asked some questions, it's still a lot of ambiguity left. However, I'll describe the easiest way I can think.

1. Turn on Runnables auto deletion
2. Create some `startedJobsCounter` and increase it every time you launch new job in the owner object.
3. Create semaphore `finishedJobsSem` that job release by one when its finishes.
4. Your `waitForFinished` for all Runnables will looks like

   finishedJobsSem.aquire(startedJobsCounter);
5. You can release `finishedJobsSem` by one in the runnable destructor.

There is no race between `startedJobsCounter` reads and writes, as all of them are preformed in owner's object thread.

As all jobs will be finished before owner object is destroed, there is no way `finishedJobsSem` will be invalid to use form the runnable.

Comment: Not only you "can" release finishedJobsSem in the destructor - you *must* do it there. If it'd be done at the end of the `run()` method, you have a race. Doing it in the destructor is the *only* place where it's safe to do so. Moreover, there are limitations as to *how* it's done in the destructor: if there are any runnable members that depend on the owner's data, the semaphore must be released after *all* of those members were destructed. Thus the semaphore must be released by an unlocker object that is the *first* member of the runnable - thus it's guaranteed to be destroyed last.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue with runnables here is the way I solved it in the end. My use case was basically that I wanted to execute the "run" method of an object in another thread and know when its done/be able to wait on it.

I found that `QtConcurrent` is actually a much nicer way than `QRunnable`.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
 void run() { }
};

void someFunc()
{
  MyClass instance;

  // Async execute "run" on "instance", returns a future
  auto future = QtConcurrent::run( std::bind(&MyClass::run,instance) );

  // Will emit "finished" signal when done - should keep this and the future in scope of course!
  QFutureWatcher watcher;
  watcher.setFuture( future );

  // Blocks until MyClass::run() returns
  future.waitForFinished();
}
```